# Problema llenando vector

Tags: c++

Hice un metodo para llenar un vector y otro para mostrarlo, cuando ejecuto el codigo me muestra el vector lleando solo con valores 0

Este es el main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

int opc, tam = 5;
vector<int> vec(tam);
llenarVector(vec, tam);
cout << "Valores del vector\n" << endl;
imprimirVector(vec, tam);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Este es el metodo para llenar el vector

```
void llenarVector(vector<int> vec, int tam)
{
  int i;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i = 0; i< tam; i++)
  { 
     vec[i] = i+1;
  }
}
```

Y este es para imprimir los valores

```
 void imprimirVector(vector<int> vec, int tam)
 {
   int i;
   for(int i=0; i< tam; i++)
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
 }
```

Estoy haciendo mal algo, aun no manejo el lenguaje C++ y el uso de vectores, gracias

Comment: Probe implementando el metodo llenarVector en el main y funciona, por alguna razon el llamado del metodo no lo esta haciendo bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con tu código es que estás pasando los parámetros de tus funciones por valor y no por referencia. 
La diferencia entre estos dos tipos de parámetros radica en que en el caso del parámetro por valor creas una copia de esa variable dentro del contexto de la función y las modificaciones se hacen a la copia y en el caso del parámetro por referencia lo que haces es pasar la dirección de esa variable como parámetro, así las modificaciones que hagas se hacen a la variable original. 
Entonces, como pasas parámetros por valor, el cambio que haces a la copia no sale de la función `llenarVector`, se queda ahí estancada. 
Te dejo el código corregido:

```
void llenarVector(vector<int> &vec, int tam)
{
  int i;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i = 0; i< tam; i++)
  {
     vec[i] = i+1;
  }
}

void imprimirVector(vector<int> &vec, int tam)
 {
   int i;
   for(int i=0; i< tam; i++)
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv){

int opc, tam = 5;
vector<int> vec(tam);
llenarVector(vec, tam);
cout << "Valores del vector\n" << endl;
imprimirVector(vec, tam);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de lo comentado por @EmmanuelLG...

La clase `vector` dispone de un método `size()` que permite conocer el número de elementos almacenados, luego la variable `tam` sobra:

```
void llenarVector(vector<int> &vec)
{
  int i;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i = 0; i< vec.size(); i++)
  {
    vec[i] = i+1;
  }
}

void imprimirVector(vector<int> &vec)
{
  int i;
  for(int i=0; i< vec.size(); i++)
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int opc;
  vector<int> vec(5);
  llenarVector(vec);
  cout << "Valores del vector\n" << endl;
  imprimirVector(vec);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Además, los bucles `for` admiten declarar variables dentro del mismo... es una buena práctica aprovechar esta característica ya que ayuda a reducir la vida de las variables y, con ello, los errores debido a descuidos:

```
void llenarVector(vector<int> &vec)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i< vec.size(); i++)
  {
    vec[i] = i+1;
  }
}

void imprimirVector(vector<int> &vec)
{
  int i; // Nota que esta declaracion te sobra.
         // esta variable es independiente de la declarada dentro del bucle
  for(int i=0; i< vec.size(); i++)
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
}
```

Y, para terminar, cuando una función reciba una referencia y no haya necesidad de modificar dicho objeto es preferible marcar dicha referencia como constante. Esto evita modificaciones que pasen desapercibidas, entre otras ventajas:

```
void imprimirVector(vector<int> const& vec)
{
  for(int i=0; i< vec.size(); i++)
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
}
```